# HTTP Head of line blocking: Why responses must come back in order

Tags: http

Head of Line blocking (in HTTP/1.1 terms) is often referring to the fact that each client has a limited number of TCP connections to a server (usually 6 connections per hostname) and doing a new request over one of those connections has to wait for the previous request on the same connection to complete before the client can make a new request.

HTTP/1.1 introduced a feature called "[Pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)" which allowed a client to send several HTTP requests over the same TCP connection. However, HTTP/1.1 still required the responses to arrive in order so it didn't really solve the HOL issue and as of today it is not widely adopted.

My question is: in HTTP pipelining, why responses must come back in order?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no identifier in the response indicating to which request it belongs.

HTTP/2 solves this with [stream identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.1.1).

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP/1.1 protocol has no way to link requests with responses, other than order. If responses could come back out of order, the client has no way of knowing which response was an answer to which request.

Worth noting that pipelining is pretty much a dead feature now though, and removed from most popular clients. If you need a feature like this, look at HTTP/2 which *does* allow out-of-order responses.